# How can show INF value in plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a data like:

```
                x         y
1  0.0000              0.38
2 1.11022302462516e-16 0.35
3  0.0000              0.33
```

First I found -log (Y) then draw a plot for X versus Y :

```
x=-log(x)
x<-replace(x,x=="Inf",0)
d<-cbind(x,y)
d <- transform(d,  x = as.numeric(x), Y = as.data.frame(y))
head (d)

     x         y
1  0.0000 0.38
2 36.7368 0.35
3  0.0000 0.33

ggplot(d,aes(x=x,y=y) + geom_point(alpha = 0.2))
```

Now I like to draw a plot that I can show Inf value (with out needing to replace INF -> zero) in it?

Comment: What do you mean by "showing" `Inf` ?

Comment: I mean , instead of Zero which I replaced with Inf. I use Inf value directly for drawing plot

Comment: You can't plot infinite values.

Comment: That still doesn't answer what showing means. How do you imagine the infinite values to show up in the plot? As a gap, as a large spike outside the boundaries of the axis, or... ?

Comment: I like show eg: as a large spike outside the boundaries of the axis. Also, I would like to know  How usually show Inf in plot?

Comment: I have never been a position where I needed to plot infinite values, so I do not know of any "Best Practice" approach to plotting `Inf` - My best bet would be: don't plot them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing `Inf`-values as arrows:

```
library(ggplot2)

myPlot <- function(data,...)
{
  n   <- which(is.finite(data$x))
  i.p <- which(is.infinite(data$x) & (data$x>0)) 
  i.n <- which(is.infinite(data$x) & (data$x<0)) 

  plt <- ggplot(data) +
    geom_point( data = data[n,], aes(x=x,y=y), ... )

  x.min <- min(data$x[n])
  x.max <- max(data$x[n])

  if (length(i.n) != 0)
  {
    plt <- plt +
      geom_segment( data      = data[i.n,],
                    aes( x    = x.min + (x.max-x.min)/10,
                         xend = x.min,
                         y    = y,
                         yend = y ),
                    linetype  = "solid",
                    arrow     = arrow(),
                    size      = 3        )
  }

  if (length(i.p) != 0)
  { 
    plt <- plt +
      geom_segment( data      = data[i.p,],
                    aes( x    = x.max - (x.max-x.min)/10,
                         xend = x.max,
                         y    = y,
                         yend = y ),
                    linetype  = "solid",
                    arrow     = arrow(),
                    size      = 3        )
  }

  return(plt)
}
```

Example:

```
data <- data.frame( x=sign(sin(1:10))*log(round(12.345*sin(1.23*(0:9))^2)), y=sqrt(1:10) )
print(myPlot(data,size=5))
```

[image]